# How do I upload a world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I'm uploading my world to [www.minecraftworldmap.com](http://www.minecraftworldmap.com), and I'm confused. How exactly DO you upload a world? I've gone into the .minecraft saves folder, but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to Get Your Favorite Minecraft World! 
(Assuming your using a windows device)

1. In the windows start menu and open the **Run** application
2. In the **Run** application enter `%appdata%`
3. Search for the `.minecraft` folder which is normally near the top.
4. In the folder are many resources like assets and logs and stats and versons and textures. We are interested in the `saves` folder.
5. Inside of the save folder you are looking for the folder that has the name of your world. It has everything you need to succeed.
6. Now to be able to send it or post it your going to need to compress it into one file.
7. Right-click on the file then to `Send to` and finally clicking on `Compressed (zipped) folder`.
8. Take your new `.zip` file and distribute it as you please.

Comment: Or press and hold Win+R to open the Run dialog box